"snapping" polygons together in python (without ArcGIS)
I have a set of polygons that partially do not touch and partially overlap. Ideally, i would like to keep the external boundary and clean up the internal edges by "snapping" the polygons together to make them share edges (see the image).
(If there is no corresponding point on polygon2 to snap it to polygon1, a new point on polygon2 should be created.)

A similar question was already asked, but the suggested solutions require ArcGIS:
"snapping" polygons together
Is there another way to do this without ArcGIS?
Thank you in advance for any suggestions for other libraries or efficient ways to write this code myself.
I had the impression that topojson might help (https://github.com/mattijn/topojson/) but i was not able to figure out how.

To clarify - do you want something that behaves the same way as ArcGIS integrate (combine points that are less than a tolerance apart) or which does what your picture shows (assuming each quad is defined by four vertices, you have combined two of the vertices for the green and blue, but made the vertices of the yellow fall on the line between the vertices of the green or blue quads)

Are you wanting 3 separate polygons or 1 combined polygon?

Topojson won't solve your problem (at the moment). Relevant for this case, it will only add points to the boundaries of adjacent polygons if they touch without a correspondent point being there. However there is no tolerance used at all, so if there is a gap or sliver of any width (or even if there is just a precision issue) no snapping will happen. So, e.g. for your "snapped polygons" drawing, the top-right point of the orange polygon might not actually have a corresponding point in the green polygon... so (if there is no rounding problem), topojson will add that point to the green polygon.

FYI: such a functionality has been announced to be on the roadmap of JTS/GEOS in one of the last paragraphs in a blogpost by one of the developers, but they didn't get to it yet...

Thank you for your questions, i have edited the post to include the answers.

@PeteKirkham if there is no corresponding point, a new one should be created.

@James i need 3 separate polygons.

@Pieter Thank you so much for explaining the functionality of topojson and the link. Too bad that the feature is not developed yet.

@Daiva as a starting point, you could have a look at geofileops.dissolve_within distance. Especially for closing gaps it might give a starting points or at least some inspiration.
